# How to iterate over files and perform action on them - Scala Spark

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, parsing, eml

I am reading 1000 of .eml files (message/email files) one by one from a directory and parsing them and extracting values from them using javax.mail api's and in end storing them into a Dataframe. Sample code below:

```
var x = Seq[DataFrame]()

val emlFiles = getListOfFiles("tmp/sample")
val fileCount = emlFiles.length
val fs = FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration)

for (i <- 0 until fileCount){
    var emlData = spark.emptyDataFrame
    val f = new File(emlFiles(i))
    val fileName = f.getName()
    val path = Paths.get(emlFiles(i))
    val session = Session.getInstance(new Properties())
    val messageIn = new FileInputStream(path.toFile())
    val mimeJournal = new MimeMessage(session, messageIn)
    // Extracting Metadata
    val Receivers = mimeJournal.getHeader("From")(0)
    val Senders = mimeJournal.getHeader("To")(0)
    val Date = mimeJournal.getHeader("Date")(0)
    val Subject = mimeJournal.getHeader("Subject")(0)
    val Size = mimeJournal.getSize
    emlData =Seq((fileName,Receivers,Senders,Date,Subject,Size)).toDF("fileName","Receivers","Senders","Date","Subject","Size")
    x = emlData +: x
}
```

Problem is that I am using a for loop to do the same and its taking a lot of time. Is there a way to break the for loop and read the files?

Comment: I suppose you could access the files in parallel with a parallel collection https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html as `(0 until fileCount).toArray.par.fold(Seq[DataFrame]())(...)`